# xdotool: how to switch to specific tab within a particular firefox window

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xdotool

let's say I have 20 tabs open across 2 Firefox windows, the URLs for which i want to save to a file. I could do it manually (with/without firefox tricks such as `% <string>` as suggested by @Chaaas). But that's not what i require.

`xdotool search --name 'Mozilla Firefox'` returns a list of X-Windows identifiers for all open Firefox windows; which can be looped over to activate individual windows using the `xdotool`'s `windowactivate` command along with the identifier. Doing this would take focus to the last active tab on the window, which i can work with, but I would require to

1. send programmed keypresses/clicks to perform the action i want,
2. send programmed keypress to close the tab
3. reiterate after a few seconds pause.

It would be much simpler if there were a mechanism for id-ing tabs instead of windows, so that I could switch to individual tabs in the first place. Can this be done using xdotool?

Comment: Are you sure what you want to achieve wouldn't be better handled with some kind of webdriver rather than using xdotool?

Comment: Short answer, yes. Long answer: I already had a simpler script which was using xdotool. Now I wanted to automate the whole flow, but xdotool appears to be too inconsistent when used like this. You're right, a webdriver is more well-suited, and probably where I'll eventually end up; after tinkering some more with xdotools.  thanks though.